# Updating permalink-property of object also updates URL in browser?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

I've created an editor for my posts using this URL scheme

`http://localhost:4200/admin/edit-post/post-permalink`

You can change `post-permalink` via ember's input-helper.

```
{{input type="text" value=permalink}}
```

How can I at the same time alter the URL in the browser to reflect the altered permalink?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/

Comment: I've never used sails.js and now I'm overwhelmed! sane looks promising as well! I'm working on my project aside, I was just using bluepring-rest-api just not to worry about the backend right now but I see it can be easily replaced with sails! And I like it.

Comment: that's cool. It has a bright future ahead with addons coming up soon (e.g. for authentification on both client and server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @andrusieczko I was able to solve this problem myself by reading the documentation http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/ :)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

permalinkChanged: function() {
   this.transitionToRoute("/admin/posts/edit/" + this.get('permalink'))
}.observes('permalink')
```

Note: I used an observer to the value instead of an action-helper because `key-press` changes the value after triggering the action.